# Windows 8.1 can't start Powershell from a cmd or powershell prompt - "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell suddenly quit opening from both cmd and powershell prompts.  I haven't installed anything new between when it did work and when it quit working.

When I try to start powershell.exe from a cmd window (both elevated and not elevated) with the following command

```
C:\Users\myuser>powershell.exe
```

I get a popup error from the OS that says:

```
This app can't run on your PC
```

Once I close that popup the cmd prompt I made the call from then prints:

```
Access is denied
```

To the screen (yes even when I do this in an elevated cmd prompt)

When I try to do it in powershell with the following command:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> powershell.exe
```

I get:

```
Program 'powershell.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : NativeCommandFailed
```

Apparently even powershell doesn't like powershell anymore.

I've tried restarting the computer and that didn't fix it, but I'm totally stymied as to what to do next.

Comment: Type `where powershell.exe` in `CMD` window.

Comment: @PetSerAl I get two locations `C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: You should not have `C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe` in normal Windows installation. And you have `C:\Windows\System32` before `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` in `PATH` environment variable, so by `powershell.exe` you call wrong file.

Comment: @PetSerAl I went and looked in the System32 folder, the powershell.exe there was 0KB.  It seems I probably opened an elevated prompt and somehow created a file called powershell.exe instead of invoking powershell. I guess I've got the dumb today  I've deleted it and It's working just fine now. Thank you!  If you care to leave an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I also have a 0 KB file named powershell in C:\Windows\System32 and I dont think its a mistake

Comment: I had this same issue, probably not a coincidence if the same corrupt file is generated for various users... hmmm. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) gave the crucial pointer in comments on the question.

The "This app can't run on your PC" pop-up error message on Windows 8 or above
[image: "This app can't run on your PC" pop-up error message on Windows 8+]
indicates:

- a **corrupted file, such as a 0-byte `*.exe` file**, esp. when followed by an "Access denied" error in the console.
- or, increasingly less commonly, an attempt to run a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit edition of Windows.

**Troubleshooting steps:**

- From a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe` console), run **`where.exe <executable-name>`**;
  from PowerShell, run **`Get-Command -All <executable-name>`**, which shows you all executables by that name present in the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable in that order, by their full paths.
  Note that `where.exe`, unlike `Get-Command`, also looks in the *current* directory, and looks there *first*.
  Thus, the *first* path returned is the executable that is actually executed when only the executable *name* is specified.

  - Note that a match in the *current* directory, if found by `where.exe`, only matters when calling the executable from `cmd.exe` (from the Command Prompt or a batch file), because PowerShell by design doesn't allow invocation of executables from the current directory by mere name.
  - If you want to run `where.exe` from PowerShell, extension `.exe` is required, because the command name `where` by itself is a built-in alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet.
- In the output from `where.exe` / `Get-Command`, check:

  - if the executable you expect is listed first.
  - if its size is non-zero.
- ***Remove* unexpected (zero-byte) executables, or, if you expect them to be there as functioning executables, *reinstall* them.**

---

**Example:**

Look for all all executables named `powershell.exe` in the current directory and in the directories listed in `$env:PATH`.

Note that the proper home of `powershell.exe` is `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, as reflected in `$PSHOME`.

**From `cmd.exe` (regular Command Prompt):**

```
where powershell.exe
```

Example output:

```
C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**From PowerShell:**

```
Get-Command -All powershell.exe
```

If you also want to look in the *current* directory, use
`Get-Command -All .\powershell.exe, powershell.exe`

Example output:

```
CommandType     Name            Version    Source
-----------     ----            -------    ------
Application     powershell.exe  0.0.0.0    C:\WINDOWS\system32\powershell.exe
Application     powershell.exe  10.0.14... C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

If you want to include the file size in the output:

```
PS> where.exe powershell.exe | % { [system.io.fileinfo] $_ |
  select fullname, length, @{ n = 'Version'; e = { $_.versioninfo.FileversionRaw } } }

FullName                                                  Length Version
--------                                                  ------ -------
C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe                             0
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 446976 10.0.14393.206
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to run an exe from PS but it kept failing. Turns out for some reason the .exe was 0 bytes. Using the correct exe fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the **powershell.exe (with 0KB)** from location **C:\Windows\System32**
In my case Powershell working fine after deleting the **powershell.exe (with 0KB)** from system 32